# Moving tables from one running extract process to other extract in golden gate

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-golden-gate

The scenario at hand is that there are 2 extract - pump - replicat groups running currently. The requirement is to move one of the tables from group2 to group1.

Can we just stop the extract-pump-replicat , remove the table entry from group2 and directly add to group1 ? will it pick up directly and start replication from where group2 ended ?

I tried a mock run with the same setup and move the table from group2 to group1 and it seemed to work fine.

wanted to know if its the best approach, or do i need to take care of any additional details. o

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go with this approach. If the target is the same and you don't want to miss any transaction - you have to make sure that all transactions till some SCN are processed by the first Extract, and the following transactions (following SCN's) are processed with the second one.

There are many ways you can achieve this:

1. Stop the activity on the source DB
2. Make sure that all transactions are processed by the both Extract processes and there is nothing more to be processed.
3. Stop both Extracts
4. Move the table between the Extracts
5. Start both Extracts

If you can not stop the source DB activity another approach would be:

1. Stop Extract #2
2. After assuring that the SCN of the Extract #1 > SCN of Extract #2, stop the Extract #1
3. Move the table between the Extracts
4. Note the SCN of the first Extract from which the table has been removed
5. Start the Extract #1
6. Stop Replicat #2
7. Add to the second Replicat parameters to filter transactions for this table from the SCN read in step 4
8. Start Replicat #2
9. Start Extract #2

Comment: In the step 6 , you mean to say , stop replicat 1 ?  because i need to stop the replciat 1 and add the map table to it

Comment: I have assumed that you had the TABLE/MAP in both Replicat processes in both scenarios. If you need to add/remove it from the Replicat param files you need of course to stop the processes for this operation. But leaving them could cause no a harm as long as no transactions come from the Extract processes.